# Azure Blob Storage Download All Files

Tags: c#, azure, download, blob, storage

I want to download all Files from the Container "$logs", but a `StorageException` is thrown.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + accName + ";AccountKey=" + accKey);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("$logs");

IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> ListBlobs = container.ListBlobs(string.Empty, true);

foreach (var item in ListBlobs)
{
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(item.ToString());
    string path= (@"C:\Users\Ay\Downloads\AzureLogs");
    blockBlob.DownloadToFile(path, FileMode.Open);
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: "storageexception the remote server returned an error (404) not found"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `item.ToString()` will return "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob" and therefore no such blob exists resulting in a 404 error.

Change that line to

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(((CloudBlockBlob)item).Name);
```

**Edit:**
The code to write the file locally is incorrect as well.
Try this

```
foreach (var item in ListBlobs)
{
    string name = ((CloudBlockBlob) item).Name;
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
    string path = (@"C:\Users\Ay\Downloads\AzureLogs\" + name);
    blockBlob.DownloadToFile(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. but now it doesnt download the files !?

Comment: There is an issue with the code to save locally as well. I've updated my answer.

Comment: this time comes this exception, but the directory already exist "directorynotfoundexception could not find a part of the path C:\Users\Ay\Downloads\AzureLogs\blob\2015\06\03\1200\000000.log"

Comment: @AyhanGzr I am facing the same error as you, Were you able to solve that?